SAS proc import imports date with dots at random place. How can I solve this problem?
I've been trying to import a csv dataset to sas, but, while it imports it correctly on colleagues computer, on mine, the date of birth are imported in a weird format, for ex.: 23.102.023 instead of 23/10/2023.
I used a classic proc import (which works for colleagues):
proc import
    file="filepathandname.csv"
    out=name
    dbms=dlm
    replace;
    delimiter=";";
    getnames=yes;
   run;

What can I do?

What exactly is text in the CSV file?  Copy the example line and paste it into your question.  What exactly is the value in the SAS variable?  Print the variable without any format attached so we can see the actual stored value instead of how it prints.  It sounds to me like the CSV file as the string 23102023 which SAS will see as just digits so it will read it as the number 23,102,023.  There is no way for PROC IMPORT to know you wanted that to be treated as DDMMYYYY instead because there is no place to store such information in a CSV file.

In the csv file, the date is separated by dots: 23.10.2023. So why would it place the dots otherwise. Why does it work for some and not others?

Possible factors, version of SAS running, and if SAS is running with Unicode Support configuration or not.  The OS settings for "Language & Region" can also affect how date representations are read and written.

If you talking about different files then since you didn't use GUESSINGROWS=MAX it could be differences in what it sees in the first 20 lines.  If you are talking about different users for the same file then difference in LOCALE settings could impact how treats values with multiple period since in some locales periods are used a thousands separator instead of as decimal point so multiple periods in a string still looks like a number.

Whether or not XX.XX.XXXX is seen as a DATE or a NUMBER by PROC IMPORT will depend on your setting of the system option LOCALE.
Let's conduct an experiment.  Let's make a simple CSV file and read it with PROC IMPORT using both LOCALE=EN_US and LOCALE=IT_IT.
options parmcards=csv;
filename csv temp;
parmcards4;
id,date
1,23.10.2023
;;;;

options locale=IT_IT;
proc import file=csv dbms=csv out=import_IT replace;
run;
options locale=EN_US;
proc import file=csv dbms=csv out=import_US replace;
run;

Note if you want another tool for guessing how a CSV should be read try the %CSV2DS macro as it will recognize DD.MM.YYYY strings as being date values whatever your LOCALE setting is.


You do not have a lot of control using proc import.
You can use infile for more control.
data read ;
infile "<path>\date_format_issue.csv" dlm="," firstobs=2 obs=20 ;
input 
    id $
    date : ddmmyy10. ;
put id= date= date7. ;

run ;

Note is is best to add the TRUNCOVER option to the INFILE so that missing values of the last field on a line of the CSV file does not cause the INPUT statement to hunt for values on the next line.
